# How to pack items (with different weights) in the smallest number of packages?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

So I have **N** items with weights: **w[1],w[2],..w[N]**, and a few bags that each can hold the weight of **M**.

The question is: How to group the items so that I can hold them **all** with the **least** number of packages?

Test case:

Items with weights **w[i]** = [40, 6, 4, 42, 8, 43, 4, 3, 19, 30].

Bag can hold **M** = 50.

An acceptable answer: (40, 6, 4) (42, 8) (43, 4, 3) (19, 30)

Comment: I believe this is a classic task for dynamic programming. Google the "return a sum of money with minimal number of coins" with dynamic programming.

Comment: @EliKorvigo yes, but this seems more advanced, since the fact that there are multiple bags probably rule out a greedy solution, right?

Comment: @EliKorvigo thank you for your reply. But my problem is slightly different with "sum of money with minimal number of coins". Just as Simon has commented. Besides, in my case, coins's sum does not always equal to the given sum. For example, in my test case: (19 + 30)=49 < 50.

Comment: I believe your problem is known as a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @m7thon Yes, thank you! I'm already looking at it~ And it seems that my problem is a lot simpler than a 3-D bin packing problem :) .

Comment: @Simon You can't solve "return a sum of money with minimal number of coins" with a greedy approach either, but rather as Eli Korvigo said you have to do it with dynamic programming. Anyway, it still is more advanced than coin-change I think.

Comment: @dingalapadum Maybe we're thinking of different coin change problems. The one I was thinking of has a greedy solution that works for some currencies but not all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Greedy_method

Comment: @Simon Yes, your problem is a special case of the general problem. For these special cases the greedy approach works. For the general case it doesn't. But how do you find out if you are in the simple or in the general case? Have a look at: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/when-can-a-greedy-algorithm-solve-the-coin-change-problem. Or you can just implement the general solution which also solves the simple special case you are talking about. In programming challenges you usually get the general problem....

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the special case of linear bin packing, where the weights are all non-negative. <strike>In this special case, the greedy First-Fit algorithm always produces the optimal solution.</strike>

The "proof" given on these set of class notes is incorrect:
http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/funAlgo/05f/lect/l5.pdf

As pointed out by @Fede, if we rearrange the inputs of the example and apply the First-Fit Algorithm, we get a non-optimal result:

w[i] = (43, 6, 4, 42, 8, 40, 4, 3, 19, 30), M = 50

FF yields (43, 6), (4, 42), (8, 40), (4, 3, 19), (30) which is 5 bags.

I would just delete this answer to avoid the shame of not thoroughly checking, but I hope this serves to prevent others from falling into the same trap.

Comment: Yep, this is a modification of Knapsack problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 2):

The first fit greedy doesn't guarantee an optimal packing. With the provided sample, a first fit could try to pack together the item that weighs 43 with the one that weighs 6, and then the resulting packing will have no less that 5 packages instead of 4.

There's probably a very efficient solution with dynamic programming, which can take advantage of having the problem solved for smaller sets of items. I'm going to propose a simple backtracking here, that you can optimize later if the performance is unacceptable.

The way I think about this is as follows. You can write a simple recursion that assigns package id to each item, with the following rules:

- First item will always be in package 0.
- Any other item can only be in packages already started, or start a new package.
- The sum of weights of items in a package cannot exceed M

Something like this would implement this set of rules.

```
int[] FindBestPackageForItems(int[] weights, int N, int M) {
    // in the worst scenario, you'll have N packages
    int lowestNumberOfBags = N;
    int[] bestPacking = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        bestPacking[i] = i;
    int[] weightInEachBag = new int[N];
    int[] currentPacking = new int[N];
    currentPacking[0] = 0; // First item is always in package 0
    weightInEachBag[0] = weights[0];
    int currentItem = 1; // Item 0 is already in bag 0, the next item to pack will be the item 1
    int usedBags = 1; // The first bag is already used by the first item
    PutItemsInBags(weights, N, M, currentPacking, weightInEachBag, currentItem, usedBags, bestPacking, ref lowestNumberOfBags);
    return bestPacking;
}

void PutItemsInBags(int[] weights, int N, int M, int[] currentPacking, int[] weightInEachBag, int currentItem, int usedBags, int[] bestPacking, ref int lowestNumberOfBags) {
    if (currentItem == N) {
        assert(usedBags < lowestNumberOfBags);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            bestPacking[i] = currentPacking[i];
        lowestNumberOfBags = usedBags;
    }
    else {
        for (int p = 0; p < min(usedBags + 1, lowestNumberOfBags); p++) {
            if (weightInEachBag[p] + weights[currentItem] <= M) {
                weightInEachBag[p] += weights[currentItem];
                currentPacking[currentItem] = p;
                PutItemsInBags(weights, N, M, currentPacking, weightInEachBag, currentItem+1, max(p, usedBags), bestPacking, ref lowestNumberOfBags);
                weightInEachBag[p] -= weights[currentItem];
            }
        }
    }
}
```